# How to trace code execution in PHP?

Tags: php, trace

I would like to see a log of THE WHOLE code execution of PHP script(s). Something like this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Standard_Library/Tracer (for lack of better example; no flame please).

Is there some way how to obtain the log in PHP?

**Note:** I know I can use a debugger but that's not the same.

Answer (score 11):

[phptrace](https://github.com/Qihoo360/phptrace) is an awesome tool to trace php code executions

Comment: That is interesting. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: I'll vote for that, because it actually answers the question, unlike the currently highest-voted answer here.  Also read the documentation page for phptrace, which has a section on comparison with other tools for execution tracing.

Comment: Sadly, an abandoned project as of 2018, which only supports PHP up to 7.1.

Answer (score 10):

Xdebug is definitely what you want, but with something like [callgrind from the valgrind suite](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) as well.

Zend blog post here should give you some pointers: http://devzone.zend.com/1139/profiling-php-applications-with-xdebug/

Answer (score 8):

In any function you can see the whole backtrace by using [`debug_backtrace(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Or you can use [Xdebug profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to profile your PHP scripts.

Comment: debug_backtrace is put on a specific place in a PHP script but I want to see a log of whole code execution - from start to the end.

Comment: Probably Didn't understand the question.  The request was for an execution tracing tool.  That's not like backtrace or profiling, but Xdebug **does** do execution tracing as well.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Kint](https://kint-php.github.io/).

[image: debug backtrace screenshot]

> It's var_dump() and debug_backtrace() on steroids. Easy to use, but powerful and customizable. An essential addition to your development toolbox.

it also has platform specific extensions [here](https://kint-php.github.io/kint/advanced/#integrations)

Comment: https://github.com/nette/tracy This is a var_dump and debug_backtrace on steroids :-)

Comment: Didn't understand the question.  The request was for an execution tracing tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PHP extension called : XHProf, developed by Facebook.

> It is capable of reporting function-level call counts and inclusive
>   and exclusive wall time, CPU time and memory usage.

https://github.com/facebook/xhprof

Comment: Xhprof is very useful for performance tracing on local and production environment but not for debugging other problems.

Comment: https://github.com/longxinH/xhprof has an updated stable release (2022.12.14).
See also http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof .

Answer (score 0):

This is what I need to traces all the lines when running php or Laravel framework in windows sub-system for linux (WSL).

Install `xdebug` in the system then edit `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini` with the following details

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.scream=0
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1

; this part here, above is used for line by line debug in vscode
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = /mnt/c/projects/www/phptraces
xdebug.trace_output_name=trace.%u
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.trace_format = 1
```

This one here

```
xdebug.trace_output_dir = /mnt/c/projects/www/phptraces
```

is the path where to store logs

For laravel framework it generate very large file most likely 4GB in size. So I used

```
split -l 1000 trace.1576842503_368392.xt pieces/traces
```

to split it into smaller parts containing 1000 lines each and store it into pieces directory.

Then you can use editor find in files what your looking for